# error won't allow me to have a large character length for blog post in flask-sqlalchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

With Flask I'm trying to make a book summary app so the posts have to be fairly long. The problem is that I get this error when my posts reach a certain amount of characters:

```html
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError

sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) index row size 3208 exceeds maximum 2712 for index "post_body_key"
HINT:  Values larger than 1/3 of a buffer page cannot be indexed.
Consider a function index of an MD5 hash of the value, or use full text indexing.
```

Here is the body column of the Post model that I used for SQLAlchemy:

```html
body = db.Column('body', db.Text(), unique=True)
```

Is there any other field other than "db.Text()" I could use where I could make my posts as long as I want without having to worry about character length?

Comment: I solved it.  In the body column of the Post model I got rid of the unique parameter and took away the parenthesis from the Text data field.  I don't know why that helped but it did.

Comment: Postgresql implements unique constraints using a unique index (implementation detail), which has its limits, as you found out. As the error suggests you could use a functional unique constraint that for example hashes the body content in order to fit in the index. On the other hand a unique constraint on such a large content seems questionable.